# How to subtract all elements in list against each other?

Tags: python, list, subtraction

I'm currently building a time calculator for running and one of my calculators is to subtract time.

Once the user enters all of their times they'd like to subtract, it would look like this:

```
TimesList = [60, 120, 240, 600]
```

My question is how could I creates some statement to subtract all the elements in the list to create some final time number? I would want some logic to do this: 600 - 240 - 120 - 60 = finaltime

Also keep in mind that the newest time is inserted at the front of the list, so subtraction would have to start at the back of the list and work to the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `functools.reduce`:

```
import functools
TimesList = [60, 120, 240, 600]
final_result = functools.reduce(lambda x, y:x-y, TimesList[::-1])
```

Output:

```
180
```

Comment: Thank you! It was a weird question to word in google so thank you for an obvious answer to it.

Comment: @BulletInAction Glad to help! Please accept this answer if it assisted you.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with the following :

```
(sum(TimesList[:-1]) * -1) + TimesList[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you want to create your own function :

```
TimesList = [60, 120, 240, 600]
def recursive(final_time,value):
    if not final_time:
        return value
    else:
        try:
            value -= final_time[1]

            return recursive(final_time[1:], value)
        except IndexError:
            return value


print(recursive(sorted(TimesList,reverse=True),sorted(TimesList,reverse=True)[0]))
```

output:

```
180
```